# bigquery pass property in commandline

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am getting an error following in bigquery :

Error: Response too large to return.

After couple of google search I found workaround is set configuration.query.allowLargeResults=true

But not sure how to pass this property value in bq command line tool.

any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ bq help query
USAGE: bq.py [--global_flags] <command> [--command_flags] [args]
[...]
  --[no]allow_large_results: Enables larger destination table sizes
  --destination_table: Name of destination table for query results.
```

So:

```
$ bq query --allow_large_results --destination_table "dataset.table" "SELECT 1"
```